# React : Pushing result of map() to an array

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to map through an array of objects and push them to a new array.

My ISSUE : only the last item of the object is being pushed to the new array

I believe this has to do with  React life cycle methods but I don't know where  I should I loop and push the values to the array to get the full list

```
//My object in an array named states
var states = [{"_id":"Virginia","name":"Virginia","abbreviation":"VN","__v":0},{"_id":"North Carolina","name":"North Carolina","abbreviation":"NC","__v":0},{"_id":"California","name":"California","abbreviation":"CA","__v":0}];

export function StateSelect()
{
   **EDIT 1**
    const options = [];

 function getStates()
{
//This is how I am looping through it and adding to an array

   { states.length > 0 &&
    states.map(item =>
    (
      console.log(`ITEM: ${JSON.stringify(item)}`),
      options.push([{ value: `${item.name}`, label: `${item.name}`}])
     ))
   }
}

return(  {getStates()}: );

}
```

Thank you

Comment: You are not returning anything from `getStates`. What is `options`? Why are you pushing arrays instead of objects to `options`?

Comment: How does this `return(  {getStates()}: );` even work ?

Comment: You probably need `return states.length > 0 && states.map(({ name }) => ({ value: name, label: name }))`

Comment: My apologies @adiga.  options is just an empty array. Please see my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your getStates() might not even be returning anything... but assuming it is, I believe you should be able to accomplish this using a `forEach()` fn in order to push values into your `options` array... Try adding the following into your map:

```
   states.map((item) => {
     console.log(`ITEM: ${JSON.stringify(item)}`);
     let processed = 0;
     item.forEach((i) => {
       options.push([{ value: `${i.name}`, label: `${i.name}`}]);
       processed++;
       if(processed === item.length) {
         // callback fn, or return
       }
    }
```

Comment: getStates() is simply updating the global variable options. The options array gets updated but only with the very last state. I tried forEach and it errored out stating forEach is not available to 'item' variable.

I am  pretty sure the issue has to do with React life cycle methods. That is where in the life cycle method do I update the options array so it keeps appending rather than overwriting

Answer (score 0):

`.map` usually used to return another result, you could just use `.forEach`

In fact, you don't really need to declare `options` at all, just use `.map` on state to return the result would be fine.

```
return states.length > 0 && states.map(({ name }) => {
  return { value: name, label: name };
});
```

Comment: You can push to an array declared with const

Comment: @nip oh god, didn't know that, more javascript chaos...

Comment: as long as you don't change `options` to something besides an array, you can keep it as a const and push items into it. But if you later change the var to `undefined`, a string, number, or anything besides the array, you're right

Comment: @lusketeer, the reason I was building options array was because I am passing that options to <Select> component in the render function so I can have those values as a drop down